# i want to toggle the class of the first child of a selected column in a row

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

i been trying to toggle the class of the first child of a selected column in a row
here is the html code:

```
         <div class="container row each-expertise">
            <div class="col l4 m4 skill-1">
                <div class="circle">
                    <i class="material-icons">phonelink_setup</i>
                </div>
                <h5>Software Development</h5>
                <p class="lead sotenue">If you have a problem to solve or an incredible  to digitally proclaim. I can help you espress it through a Web, Mobile or Desktop application. </p>
                <br class="show-on-med">
            </div>
            <div class="col l4 m4 skill-2">
                <div class="circle">
                   <i class="material-icons">web</i> 
                </div>
                <h5>Web Design and Redesign</h5>
                <p class="lead sotenue">If you need people to be informed about what you do, you need a website. You might also need a redesign if you want more from your website. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col l4 m4 skill-3">
                <div class="circle">
                    <i class="material-icons">airplay</i>
                </div>
                <h5>I.T | Tech Evangelism</h5>
                <p class="lead sotenue">I am fond of inspiring, encouraging, teaching and bringing developers &amp; I.T guys alike together to rub minds, share skills, solutions and experience. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $myskill = $("#expertise .each-expertise .col");
    $myskill.hover(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("white indigo-text text-darken-2");
      $(this).siblings().find('.circle').toggleClass('circle').toggleClass('circled');
    });

});
```

but this code seem not to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `siblings`, just:

```
$(this).find('.circle').toggleClass('circle').toggleClass('circled');
```

`Sibling()` finds all elements which are siblings of `$(this)` exclude element itself. So in siblings there are no `.circle` elements.

And as you already wrote, `toggleClass` can toggle multiple classes:

```
toggleClass('circle circled');
```

Finally:

```
$(this).find('.circle').toggleClass('circle circled');
```

As on `hover` `circle` class removed, it will be better:

```
$(this).find('.circle, .circled').toggleClass('circle circled');
```

Comment: There's no need for two toggleClass() calls

Comment: Yeah, wanted to mention. Updated.

Comment: yeah it worked but the circled class remain while it is meant to be toggled as soon as the mouse leave that area

Comment: `Circled` class remains because `circle` has been removed and your selector `$(this).find('.circle')` finds nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tv1ooo/)

You not want to use siblings() which would select the other `.col` siblings.

You need to target `.circle` and `.circled` otherwise you're leaving the first-child with the class `circled`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $myskill = $("#expertise .each-expertise .col");
    $myskill.hover(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("white indigo-text text-darken-2")
      $(this).find('.circle, .circled').toggleClass('circle circled');
    });

});
```